# Document library - attach multiple content types

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

I have to define in the `New Document` option of a document library a whole options of Microsoft documents types.

This is in SharePoint Online.

I read that I need to add the content types that I wish - such as Word, PowerPoint etc..

But I found that there is a difference in the `New` action in the ribbon and the `New` action in the list grid.

In the ribbon I have only one option:

[image]

But in the `New` option in the list grid I find more options.

How can I change the `New` option in the ribbon to be exactly like the `New` option in the grid?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of those "New" buttons please?

Answer (score 0):

Click **Change new button order and default content type** in **list settings** and make sure that each of your content type has **Visible** check mark.
Url is `/_layouts/15/ChangeContentTypeOrder.aspx?List={ListID}`

Refer to "Change the New button order or default content type" section of [this article @ support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-existing-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-9eeb0a18-b3ab-4801-ab61-d036bc8a7389#bm3).

Comment: I aware of this option order. but It is relevant If I have multiple content types attach to the document library. In that case I have only one content type, therefor Im getting only one option in the "New" option in the ribbon.but in the same document library, in the grid view, above the documents there is a additional functionality such as: new, upload and there I can create new document from any type...My question how I can have the same functionality in the ribbon

Comment: Logically, that option is irrelevant if there is **one** content type, and it's is especially designed for lists with multiple content types. Isn't http://i.imgur.com/G4Nq9CQ.png exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Oh, OK. Now I get it. That's why I was asking for screenshots

Comment: @Romi Please see http://i.imgur.com/rjXLlxa.png. Those are benefits of Office Online. AFAIK, the only supported way to emulate it is to stick with multiple content types. This might help - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-multiple-Office-templates-to-a-document-library-cde94e90-a1ba-4b94-a187-600ed68562bb